# How to extract text from text area using JavaScript and put it in Compose field of Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to send the text written in a textarea to send to the compose area of Gmail.

The problem is the output being sent is as below

> textbox=Test+mail%21&countdown=690

I just want the text to be sent.

mailto is linked to gmail.

Here is the what i have written:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <form  method="post" action="mailto:abc@gmail.com" name="myform">
<textarea name="textbox" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.textbox,this.form.countdown,700);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.textbox,this.form.countdown,700);">
</textarea>

<br>
    <font size="1">(Maximum characters: 700)<br>
    You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="700"> characters left.</font>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest what worked for me:

```
<form method="get" action="mailto:abc@gmail.com" name="myform" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
    <textarea name="body" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.textbox,this.form.countdown,700);" onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.textbox,this.form.countdown,700);"></textarea>
    <br> <font size="1">(Maximum characters: 700)<br>
    You have <input readonly type="text" size="3" value="700"> characters left.</font>

    <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
</form>
```

[See my **JSFiddle** demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/0b796tuL/1/)

Comment: Thanks, It is cleaner than earlier. If at all you get to improve and remove the "body=" please also add to the answer. It works.